# doPost "unexpected error encountered" Web Form when submitting

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm stuck on this web form after submitting.  The below code worked in a previous web form I created with the help of Serge and a few others here some time ago.  I'm attempting to re-purpose the code to make a PTO request web form.  Right now, when submitting it spits out a "unexpected error encountered error and I'm lost on attempting to locate the issue.  I'm thinking it may be how I've added panels together and their relationship?  This is a work in progress, so i know clickhandlers will be added to provide response after submit etc.  At the moment I'm looking to make sure it's passing entries in form to the spreadsheet.  Thanks for any assistance.

```
//Setting the spreadshet ID and style of the form
  var submissionSSkey = 'PUT YOUR KEY HERE'
  var PanelStyle = {'background':'#c0d6e4','padding':'40px','borderStyle':'ridge','borderWidth':'15PX','borderColor':'#31698a'}

// Script-as-app template.
function doGet(e) {
  //Creating the Appplication
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();


  //Creating panels to house the web form, instructional text, data pickers and setting style
  var vertPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setTitle('XYX Company PTO Request Form').setStyleAttributes(PanelStyle).setPixelSize(350,250);
  var mainPanel = app.createFormPanel().setPixelSize(350,150);
  var grid = app.createGrid(4,4).setId('ptogrid');
  var ptoStart = app.createDateBox().setWidth('200').setName('ptoStartDate');
  var ptoEnd = app.createDateBox().setWidth('200').setName('ptoEndDate');
  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>');

  //Assigning widgets to the grid for positioning
  grid.setText(1, 0, 'PTO Start Date')
  .setWidget(1, 1, ptoStart)
  .setText(2, 0, "PTO End Date")
  .setWidget(2, 1, ptoEnd)
  .setText(3, 0, '')
  .setWidget(3, 1, submitButton)

  //Instructions for completion of the PTO form by users.
  vertPanel.add(app.createHTML("<b>PTO Request Form</b>"));
  vertPanel.add(mainPanel);
  vertPanel.add(app.createHTML("<br><b>Instructions:</b></br>" +
                          "<p>Select the starting date and the ending date for your PTO request. "+
                          "If you are taking a single day of PTO enter the starting and ending date as the same date. "+
                           "Click Submit once you've enter the dates.  A request will be sent to your manager for reivew / approval.</p>"));

  //Grabbing active users session information in order to look up user group assignment and manager
  var employee = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  //Uses the UserManager class to get info by passing in the getActive user from base class
  var userFirst = UserManager.getUser(Session.getActiveUser()).getGivenName();
  var userLast = UserManager.getUser(Session.getActiveUser()).getFamilyName();
  var wholeName = userFirst +" "+ userLast;

  mainPanel.add(grid);
  app.add(vertPanel);
  return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ptoStart = e.parameter.ptoStartDate;
  var ptoEnd = e.parameter.ptoEndDate;
  //var wholeName = e.parameter;
  var timeStamp = new Date();


  //Access spreadsheet store values
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSkey).getSheetByName('PTO Requests');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 11).setValues([[timeStamp,ptoStart,ptoEnd]]);

  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Ok.. sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 11) was set wrong and needed to be sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the error comes from the `spreadsheet ID`, the `sheet name` or the range definition, please double check these parameters and see if it solves the issue.

I checked on my account with wrong values and it generated the same issue you have, it works as expected with correct values.

---

Edit:  your comment seems to confirm that...( didn't see it when I answered...)

Note:  the error was easy to find by looking at the execution transcript in the script editor UI, it would even give you the line of code where the error occured.

Comment: The execution transcript is so helpful.  I forgot about it since I get in and out of messing with GAS.  Thanks for the reminder..